# Theano - CNN generate feature maps after training

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, theano, conv-neural-network

After training a CNN I'm trying to run a single image through the network and plot the feature maps after the first convolutional layer. Here is my code for the CNN layer class:

```
class ConvPoolLayer(object):    
    def __init__(self, filter_shape, image_shape, poolsize=(2, 2),
                 activation_fn=sigmoid):
        self.filter_shape = filter_shape
        self.image_shape = image_shape
        self.poolsize = poolsize
        self.activation_fn=activation_fn
        # initialize weights and biases
        n_out = (filter_shape[0]*np.prod(filter_shape[2:])/np.prod(poolsize))
        self.w = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(
                np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/n_out), size=filter_shape),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(
                np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1.0, size=(filter_shape[0],)),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            borrow=True)
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]

    def set_inpt(self, inpt, inpt_dropout, mini_batch_size):
        self.inpt = inpt.reshape(self.image_shape)
        self.conv_out = conv2d(
            input=self.inpt, filters=self.w, filter_shape=self.filter_shape,
            input_shape=self.image_shape)

        self.feature_maps = theano.function([self.inpt], self.conv_out)

        pooled_out = pool.pool_2d(
            input=self.conv_out, ds=self.poolsize, ignore_border=True)
        self.output = self.activation_fn(
            pooled_out + self.b.dimshuffle('x', 0, 'x', 'x'))
        self.output_dropout = self.output # no dropout in the convolutional layers
```

I created a theano function `feature_maps` that will output the result after convolution when provided with an image (is there a cleaner way to do this?)

Then in my main code (after training), I take an image and pass it into the `feature_maps` function of the first layer object:

```
image_4d = image_2d.reshape(1, 1, 28, 28)
activations = conv_net[0].layers[0].feature_maps(image_4d)
```

I'm training this with a mini batch size of 10, so when I pass a single image in to obtain the feature maps I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The hardcoded shape for the batch size (10) isn't the run time shape (1).
Apply node that caused the error: ConvOp{('imshp', (1, 28, 28)),('kshp', (5, 5)),('nkern', 20),('bsize', 10),('dx', 1),('dy', 1),('out_mode', 'valid'),('unroll_batch', 5),('unroll_kern', 2),('unroll_patch', False),('imshp_logical', (1, 28, 28)),('kshp_logical', (5, 5)),('kshp_logical_top_aligned', True)}(<TensorType(float32, (False, True, False, False))>, <TensorType(float32, 4D)>)
Toposort index: 0
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, (False, True, False, False)), TensorType(float32, 4D)]
Inputs shapes: [(1L, 1L, 28L, 28L), (20L, 1L, 5L, 5L)]
Inputs strides: [(3136L, 3136L, 112L, 4L), (100L, 100L, 20L, 4L)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [['output']]

Backtrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):
  File "C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-8e78399125dc>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('F:/python-machine-learning/CNN/mnist.py', wdir='F:/python-machine-learning/CNN')
  File "C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 74, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "F:/python-machine-learning/CNN/mnist.py", line 53, in <module>
    conv_net = basic_conv(n=1, epochs=1)
  File "F:/python-machine-learning/CNN/mnist.py", line 47, in basic_conv
    SoftmaxLayer(n_in=100, n_out=10)], mini_batch_size)
  File "network.py", line 95, in __init__
    init_layer.set_inpt(self.x, self.x, self.mini_batch_size)
  File "network.py", line 273, in set_inpt
    input_shape=self.image_shape)
```

So it seems the complaint is that I trained with mini batches of size 10, but I'm trying to pass in a 4d array with only 1 item. Whats the correct way to fix this problem?

Also, whats really strange is that I get the error when training on CPU. When I train the exact same network on a GPU there is no such error and I get the feature map plot without a problem. I'm not sure why this difference occurs...

EDIT:

After the ConvPoolLayer there are fully connected and softmax layers at the end of the network:

Fully connected:

```
class FullyConnectedLayer(object):

    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, activation_fn=sigmoid, p_dropout=0.0):
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.activation_fn = activation_fn
        self.p_dropout = p_dropout
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.w = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(
                np.random.normal(
                    loc=0.0, scale=np.sqrt(1.0/n_in), size=(n_in, n_out)),
                dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='w', borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(
            np.asarray(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(n_out,)),
                       dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='b', borrow=True)
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]

    def set_inpt(self, inpt, inpt_dropout, mini_batch_size):
        self.inpt = inpt.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in))
        self.output = self.activation_fn(
            (1-self.p_dropout)*T.dot(self.inpt, self.w) + self.b)
        self.y_out = T.argmax(self.output, axis=1)
        self.inpt_dropout = dropout_layer(
            inpt_dropout.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in)), self.p_dropout)
        self.output_dropout = self.activation_fn(
            T.dot(self.inpt_dropout, self.w) + self.b)

    def accuracy(self, y):
        "Return the accuracy for the mini-batch."
        return T.mean(T.eq(y, self.y_out))
```

Soft max:

```
class SoftmaxLayer(object):

    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, p_dropout=0.0):
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.p_dropout = p_dropout
        # Initialize weights and biases
        self.w = theano.shared(
            np.zeros((n_in, n_out), dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='w', borrow=True)
        self.b = theano.shared(
            np.zeros((n_out,), dtype=theano.config.floatX),
            name='b', borrow=True)
        self.params = [self.w, self.b]

    def set_inpt(self, inpt, inpt_dropout, mini_batch_size):
        self.inpt = inpt.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in))
        self.output = softmax((1-self.p_dropout)*T.dot(self.inpt, self.w) + self.b)
        self.y_out = T.argmax(self.output, axis=1)  # Predicted class
        self.inpt_dropout = dropout_layer(
            inpt_dropout.reshape((mini_batch_size, self.n_in)), self.p_dropout)
        self.output_dropout = softmax(T.dot(self.inpt_dropout, self.w) + self.b)

    def cost(self, net):
        "Return the log-likelihood cost."
        return -T.mean(T.log(self.output_dropout)[T.arange(net.y.shape[0]), net.y])

    def accuracy(self, y):
        "Return the accuracy for the mini-batch."
        return T.mean(T.eq(y, self.y_out))
```

Finally, here is the code for stochastc gradient descent:

```
def SGD(self, training_data, epochs, mini_batch_size, alpha,
        validation_data, test_data, lmbda=0.0):
    """Train the network using mini-batch stochastic gradient descent."""
    training_x, training_y = training_data
    validation_x, validation_y = validation_data
    test_x, test_y = test_data

    # compute number of minibatches for training, validation and testing
    num_training_batches = size(training_data)/mini_batch_size
    num_validation_batches = size(validation_data)/mini_batch_size
    num_test_batches = size(test_data)/mini_batch_size

    # define (regularized) cost function, symbolic gradients, and updates
    l2_norm_squared = sum([(layer.w**2).sum() for layer in self.layers])
    cost = self.layers[-1].cost(self)+\
           0.5*lmbda*l2_norm_squared/num_training_batches
    grads = T.grad(cost, self.params)
    updates = [(param, param - alpha*grad)
               for param, grad in zip(self.params, grads)]

    # define functions to train a mini-batch, and to compute the
    # accuracy in validation and test mini-batches.
    i = T.lscalar() # mini-batch index

    train_mb = theano.function(
        [i], cost, updates=updates,
        givens={
            self.x:
            training_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            training_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })

    validate_mb_accuracy = theano.function(
        [i], self.layers[-1].accuracy(self.y),
        givens={
            self.x:
            validation_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            validation_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })

    test_mb_accuracy = theano.function(
        [i], self.layers[-1].accuracy(self.y),
        givens={
            self.x:
            test_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size],
            self.y:
            test_y[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })

    self.test_mb_predictions = theano.function(
        [i], self.layers[-1].y_out,
        givens={
            self.x:
            test_x[i*self.mini_batch_size: (i+1)*self.mini_batch_size]
        })

    # Do the actual training
    best_validation_accuracy = 0.0                            
    start_time = time.time()

    for epoch in xrange(epochs):
        for minibatch_index in xrange(num_training_batches):
            iteration = num_training_batches * epoch + minibatch_index

            cost_ij = train_mb(minibatch_index)

            if (iteration+1) % num_training_batches == 0:
                validation_accuracy = np.mean(
                    [validate_mb_accuracy(j) for j in xrange(num_validation_batches)])

                if validation_accuracy >= best_validation_accuracy:
                    best_validation_accuracy = validation_accuracy
                    best_iteration = iteration

                if test_data:
                    test_accuracy = np.mean(
                        [test_mb_accuracy(j) for j in xrange(num_test_batches)])
```

Comment: How do you use `mini_batch_size`?

Comment: `mini_batch_size` is used to reshape the input going into the fully connected and softmax layers, for prediction calculations, and to train mini batch gradient descent. I've added the extra code to my question